# Angular trNgGrid with Form Databinding on Gid Row Select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using [TrNgGrid](http://moonstorm.github.io/trNgGrid/release/index.html)

The idea is to update the form controls whenever a row is selected in the grid.

My form UI is

```
    <table ng-controller="moduleController" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="moduleid" class="col-md-2">Module ID : </label>
                <div class="form-group  col-md-3">

                    <input type="text" id="moduleid" name="moduleid" ng-model="hdr.moduleid" value="" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="modulename" class="col-md-2">Module Name : </label>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" id="modulename" name="modulename" ng-model="hdr.modulename" value="" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

And the controller is

```
var ap = angular.module('myApp', ['trNgGrid', 'ngRoute']);

ap.controller("moduleController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.hdr = {};

    $scope.hdr.moduleid = "";
    $scope.hdr.modulename = "None";

    $scope.mySelectedItems = [];

    //Action of clicking grid row.
    $scope.$watch("mySelectedItems[0]", function (newVal, oldVal) {
        var val;
        if (newVal != oldVal) {
            if (newVal == undefined && oldVal) val = oldVal;
            else val = newVal;
            alert("Selected Item : " + val.modulename);

            $scope.hdr = val; // CHANGES TO hdr is NOT REFLECTED
            //$scope.$apply(); // causes console error
        }
        alert($scope.hdr.modulename);
    });
});
```

Although the watch event fires but my ui is not getting updated. 
What am i missing ?

Here is a   [**JS fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x5wt6m0w/4/)   to get you started

**EDIT** : The irony is that it works in JSFiddle but not in my project. The value of hdr is duely updated. But the controls are not.

Comment: You watch empty Array in your controller, so how can your UI update?

Comment: @DieuNQ that array is populated by trNgGrid when a user selects a row

Comment: Are you sure? Because I don't see `mySelectedItems` in your html also in [trNgGrid](https://github.com/MoonStorm/trNgGrid/blob/master/trNgGrid.js)

Comment: @DieuNQ I am 100% sure.  the html for grid is not included in the question. It is included in the JSFiddle. Just visit the site for the trNgGrid  there are many example. mySelectedItems is populated by trNgGrid library dynamically.Updated Fiddle

Comment: @DieuNQ Updated the fiddle. check it out

Comment: Congrats. You solved your own problem.

Comment: @DieuNQ Thanks but the same thing does not update in my project although it works in JSFiddle.