# Angular $watch not updating UI

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a $watch in which i am updating my model. But my model fails to update the bound controls in UI.

Here is a screenshot of updated model.
[image]

my ui has this

```
<form method="post" action="" role="form" class="form-horizontal form-group-sm">

    <table ng-controller="myController" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="moduleid" class="col-md-2">Module ID : </label>
                <div class="form-group  col-md-3">

                    <input type="text" id="moduleid" name="moduleid" ng-model="hdr.moduleid" value="" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="modulename" class="col-md-2">Module Name : </label>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" id="modulename" name="modulename" ng-model="hdr.modulename" value="" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="status" class="col-md-2">Status : </label>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">

                    @Html.DropDownList("status", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.StatusList, new { @class = "form-control ComboM required", @ng_model = "hdr.status", @style = "width: 240px" })
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Why is this failing to update my UI.

**EDIT** : tried the following too. still no luck.

```
   $scope.$watch("mySelectedItems[0]", function (newVal, oldVal) {
        var val;
        if (newVal != oldVal) {
            if (newVal == undefined && oldVal)
                $scope.hdr = oldVal;
            else $scope.hdr = newVal;
        }
        //    alert($scope.hdr.modulename);
    });
```

EDIT 2 : works in [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x5wt6m0w/4/) but not in my project. Please see the original [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684772/angular-trnggrid-with-form-databinding-on-gid-row-select)

Answer (score 1):

Your `$scope.hdr` seems to be an Object. Objects are bound by reference in JS (just like Arrays). You set your `$scope.hdr = y` and that causes to break this reference. Your binding won't update as result. Depending on your Objects content, you may try `angular.extend` or `angular.merge`:

```
angular.extend($scope.hdr, y);
```

**Documentation:**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

Comment: thanks. But check this JS Fiddle it works in there !! https://jsfiddle.net/x5wt6m0w/4/

Comment: @Deb: Well, that's another solution :) You are watching `mySelectedItems[0]`, so `newVal` already holds the correct reference. You then apply this reference to your `$scope.hdr` via `val` and cause the update. At least that's how I understand what's going on :)

Comment: y is also an object which is part of collection mySelectedItems.

Comment: Also this is repost of my original question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684772/angular-trnggrid-with-form-databinding-on-gid-row-select

Comment: Hmm... Have you tried to not bind `var x = $scope.mySelectedItems;` but `var x = newVal;` (just like you did it in your fiddle)?

Comment: tried watching collection as well as collection[0]. both works in jsfiddle but not budge in my project :(

Comment: Strange. Maybe the error is not in your angular, but in asp.net? Have you tried to implement this as angular/JS/HTML only in your project, asp.net gui code aside?